# WPF - MenuItem missing Icon/Image

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, icons, menuitem

Im getting menuItem icon appearing only on last menuItem.
If i snoop the app only last menuItem has image in icon, while if i debug all MenuItems appear to have image in icon. Also if i add submenuItem the icon on menuItem dissapears once i open submenus and the last submenu gets the icon... Any idea? PS: also tooltips on menu item dont work.
Im using caliburn micro and fluent ribbon controls.

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="dropDownButton">
        <ef:DropDownButton Header="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                           LargeIcon="{Binding LargeIconPath}" 
                           cm:Message.Attach="ClickAction()" 
                           ef:KeyTip.Keys="{Binding KeyTip}">
            <ef:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" 
                            Value="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Icon">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=IconPath}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                            Value="{Binding Items}"/>
                    <Setter Property="cm:Message.Attach" 
                            Value="ClickAction()"/>
                    <Setter Property="ef:KeyTip.Keys" 
                            Value="{Binding KeyTip}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ef:ScreenTip Title="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                          HelpTopic="ScreenTip help ..."
                                          Image="{Binding LargeIconPath}"
                                          Text="Text for ScreenTip"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ef:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ef:DropDownButton.ToolTip>
                <ef:ScreenTip Title="{Binding DisplayName}"
                              HelpTopic="ScreenTip help ..."
                              Image="{Binding LargeIconPath}"
                              Text="Text for ScreenTip"/>
            </ef:DropDownButton.ToolTip>
        </ef:DropDownButton>
```

Comment: IMHO the solution to the similar topic: " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177550/menuitem-style-with-icon-creates-only-one-icon " is a better one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are setting `Icon` property to an `Image` control in `Style`. Now, only one copy of `Style` is created and thus, only one copy of `Image` is created. Now, any control can have only one parent at a time. So, when it is assigned to last `MenuItem`, it is removed from previous `MenuItem` controls. To fix this, use `Templates`.

Instead of setting `Header` property, set `HeaderTemplate`:

```
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0"
                                   Source="{Binding Path=IconPath}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

I'm not sure of what properties are exposed by the control toolkit you are using. But, I'm sure they must have a template property.

After doing this, you don't need to set `Icon` property in style.

Comment: in trying to use this, yet its not clear to me. Im getting Error: 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate' property on a Setter.

Comment: My mistake. You have to wrap it in `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 3):

I successfully use the following entries in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<!-- Define non-shared image to avoid loss of menu icons -->
<Image x:Key="MenuIconImage" Height="16" Width="16" x:Shared="false">
    <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage Drawing="{Binding Icon}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DisplayName />
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIconImage}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I am using Textblock & rectangle as Icon instead of image

Answer (score 0):

Works like this:

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemHeaderTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Path=IconPath}" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding DisplayName}" />               
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


    <ControlTemplate x:Key="dropDownButton">
        <ef:DropDownButton Header="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                           LargeIcon="{Binding LargeIconPath}" 
                           cm:Message.Attach="ClickAction()" 
                           ef:KeyTip.Keys="{Binding KeyTip}">
            <ef:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemHeaderTemplate}" />                                 
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                            Value="{Binding Items}"/>
                    <Setter Property="cm:Message.Attach" 
                            Value="ClickAction()"/>
                    <Setter Property="ef:KeyTip.Keys" 
                            Value="{Binding KeyTip}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ef:ScreenTip Title="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                          HelpTopic="ScreenTip help ..."
                                          Image="{Binding LargeIconPath}"
                                          Text="Text for ScreenTip"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ef:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ef:DropDownButton.ToolTip>
                <ef:ScreenTip Title="{Binding DisplayName}"
                              HelpTopic="ScreenTip help ..."
                              Image="{Binding LargeIconPath}"
                              Text="Text for ScreenTip"/>
            </ef:DropDownButton.ToolTip>
        </ef:DropDownButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason approach when Image is static resource with x:Shared = false doesn't work for me. Only last menu item shows icon. I've tried both StaticResource and DynamicResource. Here is my solution:

```
public class MenuItemIconHelper
{
    #region ImageSource Icon

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Icon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MenuItemIconHelper), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource), IconPropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void IconPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var i = (MenuItem)obj;

        if (e.NewValue != null)
            i.Icon = new Image() {Source = (ImageSource)e.NewValue};
        else
            i.Icon = null;
    }

    public static void SetIcon(DependencyObject element, ImageSource value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IconProperty, value);
    }

    public static ImageSource GetIcon(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ImageSource)element.GetValue(IconProperty);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Sample:

```
<Style x:Key="CommandMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
<Setter Property="cb:MenuItemIconHelper.Icon" Value="car1.png" />
<Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
```

I consider it to be more readable than using resource and you don't need to change MenuItem's HeaderTemplate. You can also implement some caching mechanism for ImageSource or Image.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add Existing File...** image file to resources (if you already have one, skip it).

[image]

**2.** In **Solution Explorer** select this image file.

**3.** Change **Build Action** to **Resource**.

[image]

**And finally,** you can add this image to XAML with simple call:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu" >
        <MenuItem Header="Restart" Name="menuItemRestart" Click="MenuItem_Click">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="/Resources/restart.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Name="menuItemExit" Click="MenuItem_Click">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="/Resources/window_close.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

**The Result:**
[image]