# MenuItem style with icon creates only one icon

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Im having a problem rendering icons for a dynamic menu which uses viewmodels as an ItemsSource.
The solution I've used is outlined here 
[MVVM Dynamic Menu UI from binding with ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392160/mvvm-dynamic-menu-ui-from-binding-with-viewmodel/4816588#4816588)

The basic layout is as follows

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HeaderedItemViewModel}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
      <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"></ContentPresenter>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Header}" />
      <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding Path=InputGestureText}" />
      <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}" />
      <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" Height="16px" Width="16px" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Menu Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shell.Navigation.Menus}" />
</Grid>
```

In the above style the binding 'Icon' is 'ImageSource'. This is set up as follows.

```cs
        BitmapImage image = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath))
        {
            image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Relative));
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        }
        var menu = new HeaderedItemViewModel
                       {
                           Header = header,
                           InputGestureText = inputGesture,
                           ImagePath = imagePath,
                           Icon = image,
                           Command = command,
                           IsEnabled = isEnabled
                       };
```

The problem I'm having is with the icons.
It seems only one icon will render at a time? Heres what I mean.

[image]

And opening the dropdown menu ...

[image]

As soon as another image is rendered the first one disappears? In other words only the last image is visible. This happens with all the images in the menu. Any ideas?

Comment: One question: How do you setup the actual input bindings, binding to InputGestureText will not setup the actual input bindings.

Comment: I'm not currently using input bindings. This may possibly help you further. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/10/29/new-wpf-features-key-gesture-binding.aspx. By extending the command class you can then map these to your input bingings collection from the ViewModel.

Comment: @bitbonk: Yes the gesture is bound as defined above. I have a class called NavigationViewModel that creates and initializes all the menus and toolbars. Theses all derive from a class called HeaderItemViewModel. This means I can reuse instance for menuitems that also appear in the toolbar. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add x:Shared=false for your Icon value.
To do that you should declare Image in resources:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>

   <Image x:Key="imgCTX" x:Shared="false"
         Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" Height="16px" Width="16px"/>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HeaderedItemViewModel}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
      <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"></ContentPresenter>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Header}" />
      <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding Path=InputGestureText}" />
      <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource imgCTX}" />
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Menu Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shell.Navigation.Menus}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: That works great, thanks. One small problem though is using height and width in the image resource. This causes the top level menus to spread out even though they don't have images. I suppose i could just rescale the images and be done with it. Any idea how to apply height and width only when theres actually an image available?

Comment: I suppose I could add these to the viewmodel and bind them directly, thats probably the easiest way.

Comment: Also, theres a typo in your answer, <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource = imgCTX}" /> should read <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource imgCTX}" />

Comment: How did you prevent the top level menu items from sizing according to the underlying menu items?

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Had the same problem here today. Your answer solved it. Thx a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I've searched various responses and the x:Shared="false" thing is surely helping but you need also to setup all properly to make it sure it works and it took me a bit to find the proper solution. This is how I've make it working on my side

```
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuElements}">
            <ContextMenu.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuSeparatorTemplate">
                    <Separator />
                </ControlTemplate>
                <Image
                    x:Key="MenuIcon"
                    Width="16"
                    Height="16"
                    x:Shared="False"
                    Source="{Binding Icon}" />
            </ContextMenu.Resources>
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Childs}" />
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Run}" />
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSeparator}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
```

This way I've been able to make my context menu to dynamically load the icons depending on the input.