# WPF: Byte array to Image on a button in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Image control contains no image.]

I have tried many combinations of things but with no joy.

Here is what i think should work, but I get a blank button:

```
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)ic.ConvertFrom myByteArray);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();

bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0

BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();

brush.ImageSource = bi;
button.Background = brush;
```

Any suggestions welcome... this has to be done in the code behind also.

## EDIT:

Sorry, just to add that I am using WPF, MVVM approach.

This code works on one dialog window but **NOT** on another:

So I open a dialog window from the main window and then open another dialog window, this code shows the image on the buttons fine... however when i open a 3rd dialog window, and try the same code, the buttons are blank...

```
_stockButtons[i].Width = 100;
_stockButtons[i].Height = 100;

ImageBrush brush2 = new ImageBrush();
BitmapImage bitmap2 = new BitmapImage();
bitmap2.BeginInit();
bitmap2.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Kevin\Pictures\test.jpg");
bitmap2.EndInit();
brush2.ImageSource = bitmap2;
_stockButtons[i].Background = brush2;
```

If I use the above code to load the images into the buttons on the initial load of the window, the images are displayed OK... The issue seems to be when I select a button on the left column, then I display an amount (1 or more) of buttons for the items related to the clicked department. The image seems to be lost somewhere or not being pulled in correctly? Does that makes sense?

### XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Views.WindowsViews.SelectStockDialogWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:ViewModels;assembly=ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxd="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:Support="clr-namespace:Support;assembly=Support"
    xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Royale"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Title="Select stock item"
    mc:Ignorable="d" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="585" Height="600" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Views;component/Styles/Brushes.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <dxd:DockLayoutManager Name="dlSalesScreen">
        <dxd:DockLayoutManager.LayoutRoot>
            <dxd:LayoutGroup Name="Root" Orientation="Horizontal" AllowSplitters="False">

                <dxd:LayoutPanel AllowClose="False" AllowRename="False" 
                                 Caption="Departments" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                 CaptionAlignMode="AutoSize"
                                 CaptionImageLocation="BeforeText" ShowPinButton="False" >

                    <!-- Scrollviewer for department buttons-->
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="deptScrollviewer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="185" Height="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Orientation="Vertical" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </dxd:LayoutPanel>

                <dxd:LayoutPanel AllowClose="False" AllowRename="False" 
                                 Caption="Available stock in department" Width="Auto" 
                                 CaptionAlignMode="AutoSize" 
                                 CaptionImageLocation="BeforeText"  ShowPinButton="False">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!-- Scrollviewer for stock buttons-->
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="stockScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StockItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="Auto" Fill="{StaticResource BottomRectangleGradient}" />
                        <Grid Name="gridButtonHolder" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <GroupBox x:Name="grpStockItem" Grid.Column="0" Header="Selected Item" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" >
                                <Label x:Name="lblStockName" Content="{Binding SelectedStockItemLabel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            </GroupBox>
                            <Button Name="btnSave" Content="Apply" Command="{Binding ConfirmSelectionCommand}" dxc:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Blue" Grid.Column="1" Width="110" Height="42" Margin="0,8,0,0" />
                            <Button Name="btnClose" Content="Cancel" dxc:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Blue" Grid.Column="2" Width="110" Height="42" Margin="0,8,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </dxd:LayoutPanel>
            </dxd:LayoutGroup>
        </dxd:DockLayoutManager.LayoutRoot>
    </dxd:DockLayoutManager>
</Window>
```

Comment: add this line `bitmap2.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;` between your `BeginInit` and `EndInit`.

Comment: thanks Nacereddine.. didnt work unfortunately but i added a screen shot there to show exactly what should be happening :) Both collections and all code is in the same viewmodel for this view. And im simply binding the button collections to a control in the XAML... Ive tried binding to Button[] array and ObservableCollections just to see if it would make a difference .. Thanks again

Comment: @kev: Can you post the relevant XAML markup. I have a suspicion the problem may be similar to the one I had here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177550/menuitem-style-with-icon-creates-only-one-icon

Comment: I have even tried something simple like changing the background colour... it wont even change colour! I can change the content ok but the colour wont even change... I tried assigning a new style to the button with a setter to get a new brush colour and i tried changing the colour directly... it seems to be an issue with loading the buttons dynamically on the window when the window has been loaded already.. but how could i change the content and not the colour?? COnfussssssssssed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (without using the WinForms images)

```
ImageBrush brush;
BitmapImage bi;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(myByteArray))
{
    brush = new ImageBrush();

    bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bi.StreamSource = ms;
    bi.EndInit();
}

brush.ImageSource = bi;
button.Background = brush;
```

Comment: Mmmm no luck on that im afraid

Comment: @Kev What do you mean ? Is there any error messages ? How do you obtain you `myByteArray` array ?

Comment: I have the byte array in a public property in the same class, using a getter  to retrieve the byteArray from a model entity. I have checked it and its there... Thing is if I use 'URISource' to get the path of a test picture it works

Comment: ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
                        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmap.BeginInit();
                        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Picture.jpg");
                        bitmap.EndInit();
                        brush.ImageSource = bitmap;
                        button.Background = brush;

Comment: Sorry there is an error message in the bitmap image : "BitmapMetadata is not available on BitmapImage."

Comment: Stacktrace:  at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.get_Metadata()

Comment: Check the data you're getting from your model entity.

Comment: Ive edited my original post. Data from entity is fine but ive use some test code to get an image using 'UriSource' and it works on 1 dialog window for its buttons but not on another... which leads me to think its my code? Both windows are using Button[] arrays

Comment: Nacereddines answer is correct for my original issue as stated in the title. I have realised that the issue goes a little deeper but his answer is correct for the original question. Many thanks for everyones help