# Unable to display Image created from Base64 BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bitmap, base64

I want to display an Image in a `StackPanel` from a base64 string but it's not working correctly.

```
string base64encodedImage = el.Value;
byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64encodedImage);

Image imageSection = new Image();
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
{
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = memStream;
    image.EndInit();
}

imageSection.Source = image;

panel.Children.Add(imageSection);
```

Example Base64 Image:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

The `BitmapImage` gets a width and height, the `Image` however does not and nothing is displayed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481189/wpf-byte-array-to-image-on-a-button-in-code-behind) post to find the correct way to get the `BitmapImage` from byte array.