# ContextMenu too-wide WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I have built a ContextMenu dynamically using MVVM. The problem is : the content of MenuItems is all in right side ==> too wide ContextMenu. Do you have any ideea which is the problem? Thanks

Here is the code in XAML:

```
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="RightClickMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.MenuItemsList}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- <MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding Command}" -->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding MyIcon}"  Width="18" Height="18" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                        <MenuItem  Header="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding Command}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem}"
                                  />
                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.ContextMenu>
```

It looks like :

[image]

I want the ContextMenu to be like this:

[image]

The second problem:

[image]

Sometimes it works well but sometimes I get these strange things.

------------------------------Solved--------------------------------------------

For Sac1. I have modified your solution by adding x:Shared="False". Check MSDN for x:Shared.

```
     <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Shared="False"> 
                <Setter Property="Icon">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyIcon}" Height="20" Width="20"  >
                        </Image>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"  />
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem}" />
            </Style>
```

For the wrong headers of menu items I had to override the method ToString() in MenuItemViewModel. I don't undestand why I had to override ToString() but it works well now.

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : BindableBase
{
......
 public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return model.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.model.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

 public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
   ....
  }
```

Comment: second: Insert your `MenuItemsList` and `MenuItemViewModel` code pls
(It looks like Header setter is not workink properly) Any error in Output window?

Comment: Your style is overwritten or not applied correctly. Missing Setter for Header. Missing Name Property in MenuItemViewModel. Possible workaround is override ToString of MenuItemViewModel, buit I think your command is stayed 'fuzzy'...

Comment: I have the problem like this guy had and I think this is the reason :             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177550/menuitem-style-with-icon-creates-only-one-icon

Comment: So what was your problem, Icon or text?

Comment: That means I  just have an icon for last MenuItem . I think in case I resolve this problem I wont see TreeView..... in ContextMenu

Comment: If  you look at third image you will get the ideea.

Comment: That's why you use same icon, and during 'generation' your icon changes its parent continously.
I had a 'dirty' solution for this. ViewModel MyIcon property is a Rectangle not an Image. New Rectangle for every Item.

Comment: I  can't figure out how to use x:Shared="False"

Comment: <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Shared="False">... </Style>  All Icons appears but the problem with Treeview.ViewModel.MenuItemViewModel still persits

Comment: I have override ToString() method of MenuItemViewModel and it works well. Thanks for help sac1

Comment: it"s dirty. Could you insert your style and view model?

Comment: I have post something.

Comment: And There aren't any errors in Output after you open ContextMenu, are there? Do you have DataTemplate for this ViewModel, or HeaderTemplate setup...? You could try to modify Header setter to hardcoded string. If it is not appeare, your style is overriden partially..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTemplate` of `MenuItem` is not working as expected.
I used Style insted of DataTemplate:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding MyIcon}" />
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem}" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.MenuItemsList}" />
</TreeView.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a `DataTemplate` for the `ContextMenu`. Just use it as provided:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
              Icon="{Binding Path=MyIcon}"
              Header="{Binding Path=Name}"
              InputGetstureText="CTRL+O" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use MenuItem in DataTemplate instead use button with BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"