# MenuItem.Icon appears only on the last item

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, icons

I have a Menu with the following style on the items:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Ic</TextBlock>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubItems}"/>
</Style>
```

(`Name`, and `SubItems` are properties of the class `MenuItem`.
the `ItemsSource` property of the menu is bound to an object of type `List<MenuItem>` )

problem is the "Icon" part appears only on the last item of the menu:

[image]

Furthermore, if I click to expand the "Playlist" Item here's what happens:
[image]

I ultimately want to bind each Item to its own Icon, but that doesn't seem to work either. 
Any ideas what causes this misbehavior and how to fix it?

**update** I've seen this: [MenuItem style with icon creates only one icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177550/menuitem-style-with-icon-creates-only-one-icon)
but it didn't work for me because a. `x:Shared=false` made a `XamlParseException` and b. if I moved it out of the `Style.Resources` it didn't make an exception but simply didn't work. Note that I do need this INSIDE the Style because ultimately I want it to be bound to a property of the class I'm binding the MenuItem to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MenuItem style with icon creates only one icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177550/menuitem-style-with-icon-creates-only-one-icon)

Comment: Seen it, didn't work for me. Setting x:Shared=false made an exception. when I moved it to be a ResourceDictionary outside the style it didn't throw an exception but didn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Don't Share the TextBlock

```
 <TextBlock x:Key="tb"  x:Shared="false" FontWeight="Bold">Ic</TextBlock>


<Style  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    ...             
   <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource tb}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: `x:Shared` works for items inside ResourceDictionary, while this TextBlock is not there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, but its kind of ugly. I guess the "Ic" is only a placeholder, but my answer will get you the idea how to do that in other cases.

In my example `{x:Null}` is a placeholder, normally you'd bind to a field in your viewmodel and use converter to build an `Image` instance from that field's value.

```xml
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Source={x:Null}, Converter={StaticResource TextBlockConverter}}" />
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubItems}"/>
</Style>
```

```cs
public class TextBlockConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "Ic";
            FontWeight = Bold
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```