# MenuItem not showing image at running time

Tags: wpf, xaml

### What do I have

I've a menu, where my third `MenuItem` doesn't have a text header, but an image. Being the code the following for this element:

```
<MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
  <MenuItem.Header>
    <StackPanel>
      <Image Source="/Resources/Button.gif" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
    </StackPanel>
  </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

### Problem

While this code seems to be correct, and the button looks fine at the design view, when I debug my app, the `menuItem` collapses like if it were empty.

In fact, If I put my mouse over where the item should be, the item becomes blue and it can be observed that its size is quite small.

**Why does it happen? How can I avoid it?**

### Pics

First one with the view at the design window:

[image: Design view]

Second one debugging the app:

[image: Debug pic]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure the build action of your Button.gif image is set to Resource not Content !

Comment: what is the build action of Image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the properties of image in Visual studio solution explorer and set Build Action to Resource(some other options will also work)

[image: Build Action]

Rebuild your solution and image will be available in view at run time.

Also read a relative topic if this is not your problem [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398954/wpf-menuitem-missing-icon-image?rq=1)

Comment: This worked, but also had to modify `/Resources/Button.gif` to `Resources/Button.gif`. Thanks!

Comment: @BtcSources logically if you are able to see the image with '/' prefix in designer then that should work at run time too. And I think this will work with '/' too. It's working for me. But thanks for pointing out.